# Which an annotation @Autowired is not recommended for use by developers Spring and why?

Tags: java, spring

Which  from ways **Autowiring for beans** is not recommended for use by **developers** **Spring** and why ?

**(I mean why they don't recommend to use @Autowired)**

When we specify for **Spring** which **beans** it should embed in other classes, then we for example, use **@Autowired**.

But this annotation is not recommended for use, but **Data Binding** is recommended why ?.

**This is the following answer as an additional one**(may be related indirectly to the main question)...

Who can explain the pitfalls in this issue and how is different   to set the annotation **@Autowired** over the constructor or setter, in which cases what is preferable ?

Comment: This is not a duplicate, please read the question carefully. The question about the installation over the constuctor or over the setter is as an addition to the main one, or rather as a companion.

Answer (score 2):

There is a quite good explanation written by the Spring team in their [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-dependencies), where it says:

> Constructor-based or setter-based DI?
>
> Since you can mix constructor-based and setter-based DI, it is a good
> rule of thumb to use constructors for mandatory dependencies and
> setter methods or configuration methods for optional dependencies.
> Note that use of the @Required annotation on a setter method can be
> used to make the property be a required dependency; however,
> constructor injection with programmatic validation of arguments is
> preferable.
>
> The Spring team generally advocates constructor injection, as it lets
> you implement application components as immutable objects and ensures
> that required dependencies are not null. Furthermore,
> constructor-injected components are always returned to the client
> (calling) code in a fully initialized state. As a side note, a large
> number of constructor arguments is a bad code smell, implying that the
> class likely has too many responsibilities and should be refactored to
> better address proper separation of concerns.
>
> Setter injection should primarily only be used for optional
> dependencies that can be assigned reasonable default values within the
> class. Otherwise, not-null checks must be performed everywhere the
> code uses the dependency. One benefit of setter injection is that
> setter methods make objects of that class amenable to reconfiguration
> or re-injection later. Management through JMX MBeans is therefore a
> compelling use case for setter injection.
>
> Use the DI style that makes the most sense for a particular class.
> Sometimes, when dealing with third-party classes for which you do not
> have the source, the choice is made for you. For example, if a
> third-party class does not expose any setter methods, then constructor
> injection may be the only available form of DI.

So in general it is recommended to use constructor injection for mandatory fields and setter injection for optional fields, but be careful, because if you are using setter injection, you renounce the goodness of immutables. What is discouraged is definetely field injection, as it needs to use java reflection mechanism to populate your fields, which has this consequence that you couple your code very tightly with spring's mechanisms and also it makes your unit tests much harder, as you cannot so easilly pass a mock object via a constructor or setter.

Comment: Setter injection also forces bean creation, so actually it is created at the same time as it would be created with the constructor injection. Then why is such dependency supposed to be "optional" in the documentation?

Comment: Or do they mean some service dependencies, like logger? (Optional in terms of functionality, not technically)

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by "Setter injection also forces bean creation, so actually it is created at the same time as it would be created with the constructor injection." - Yes, they are created at the same time, difference is, that when using constructor injection, your object is all set and ready to be used, while with setter injection, there is some moment of inconsistency, because all fields are initialized with default values (0, null, false) and are set later. Setter injection is good, when the dependency is not crucial - meaning, your object can work properly without it.